# Make a huge dict from multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I am trying to transform multiple numpy arrays in a huge dictionary of tasks in python. I am sure this problem has been solved, but I am not sure how to search for such result. 
Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

I'm getting mixed up with `for` and `while` loops in my tries. If someone as a relatively efficient way of solving this, ideally, I wish to be able to add as many keys to the initial dict without changing the function to generate the output.

```
#INPUT
initial = {
         'diameter': array([ 20.,  30.,  40.]),
         'medium': array([ 1, 1.5, 2]),
         'thickness': array([ 100, 150, 200]),
         'density': array([1])
         }

#OUTPUT
output = {
   "task1":{'id'=1, 'diameter':20, 'medium':1, 'thickness':100, 'density':1},
   "task2":{'id'=2, 'diameter':30, 'medium':1, 'thickness':100, 'density':1},
   "task3":{'id'=3, 'diameter':40, 'medium':1, 'thickness':100, 'density':1},
   "task4":{'id'=4, 'diameter':20, 'medium':1.5, 'thickness':100, 'density':1},
   "task5":{'id'=5, 'diameter':30, 'medium':1.5, 'thickness':100, 'density':1},

           ...

   "taskN":{'id'=N, 'diameter':40, 'medium':2, 'thickness':200, 'density':1},
```

Comment: are looking for all possible combinations?

Comment: does the output dict have to be in that order, if not you can solve this quite easily

Comment: Define "huge". Maybe is not as big as you imagine ;) . That will influence the kind of solutions people can suggest.

Comment: Huge, means each diameter, mediu, etc... might have shapes pretty large with more that a 100 values. and I might add more "parameters". It might not be huge in terms on programming, but, it is still a considerable number of tasks. I'll try @aws_apprentice answer which looks great, and see if I run into issues if the initial dict is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the final ordering of `output` is not important you can achieve this using `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

all_prods = product(*initial.values())
output = dict()
keys = ('id', *initial.keys())
count = 1

for prod in all_prods:
    vals = (count, *prod)
    ready = zip(keys, vals)
    output.update({'task{}'.format(count): dict(ready)})
    count += 1

output

{'task1': {'id': 1,
  'diameter': 20.0,
  'medium': 1.0,
  'thickness': 100,
  'density': 1},
 'task2': {'id': 2,
  'diameter': 20.0,
  'medium': 1.0,
  'thickness': 150,
  'density': 1},
 'task3': {'id': 3,
  'diameter': 20.0,
  'medium': 1.0,
  'thickness': 200,
  'density': 1},
...etc
```

If order does matter then we should pre-sort beforehand

```
from operator import itemgetter

initialize same variables as before...

for prod in sorted(all_prods, key=itemgetter(1,2)):
    same as before....


output

{'task1': {'id': 1,
  'diameter': 20.0,
  'medium': 1.0,
  'thickness': 100,
  'density': 1},
 'task2': {'id': 2,
  'diameter': 30.0,
  'medium': 1.0,
  'thickness': 100,
  'density': 1},
 'task3': {'id': 3,
  'diameter': 40.0,
  'medium': 1.0,
  'thickness': 100,
  'density': 1},
 'task4': {'id': 4,
  'diameter': 20.0,
  'medium': 1.0,
  'thickness': 150,
  'density': 1},
  ...etc
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? It is a legit answer. If not, please explain why.

Comment: probably the other guy retaliating because his answer wasn’t correct, it is what it is

Comment: You have my +1 vote for using the `product` function.

Comment: haha thanks yes the other person deleted his answer, didn’t even try to fix it

Comment: That's brilliant! I've never heard of `product`. If I may push the answer and your kindness slightly: If i wanted to add objects to each task (with your answer I get `TypeError: 'object_name' object is not iterable`) how would you do that, basically each task would be `'task1': {'id': 1, **'metal': <object>**, diameter': 20.0,   'medium': 1.0,   'thickness': 100,  'density': 1},` where the initial would be `initial = { 'metal': <object>, 'diameter': array([ 20.,  30.,  40.]) ...  }`

Comment: you will have to elaborate on that, is metal a constant?

Comment: It's a django model class `<class 'app_name.models.class_name'>`. Does that help?

Comment: is it going to be in the initial dict? I suggest making a new question as that would be a new question with a new ask

Comment: So you would define output as `output = {"metal":<object>}` ? If no, I'll make a new question. EDIT: I've anwsered maybe too fast, let me try it first ^^. I'll get back to you

Comment: EDIT2: did not work :), here's the new question as @aws_apprentice suggested [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445012/adding-default-keys-to-itertools-product-for-making-dict-from-numpy-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445012/adding-default-keys-to-itertools-product-for-making-dict-from-numpy-lists)

Comment: EDIT3: actualy deleted the post as the answer is pretty straightforwards. Didn't take the time to think about it

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive function to enumerate combinations. This code sample does not do the whole thing but it gives you an idea how to build your output dictionary.

```
initial = {
    'diameter': array([20.,  30.,  40.]),
    'medium': array([1, 1.5, 2]),
    'thickness': array([100, 150, 200]),
    'density': array([1])
}

def unpack(fields, data, acc):
    if not fields:
        yield acc
    else:
        field = fields.pop()
        for value in data[field]:
            acc[field] = value
            yield from unpack(fields, data, acc)
        fields.append(field)


fields = list(initial.keys())
for record in unpack(fields, initial, {}):
    print(record)
```

The result is like

```
{'density': 1, 'thickness': 100, 'medium': 1, 'diameter': 20.0}
{'density': 1, 'thickness': 100, 'medium': 1, 'diameter': 30.0}
{'density': 1, 'thickness': 100, 'medium': 1, 'diameter': 40.0}
{'density': 1, 'thickness': 100, 'medium': 1.5, 'diameter': 20.0}
{'density': 1, 'thickness': 100, 'medium': 1.5, 'diameter': 30.0}
{'density': 1, 'thickness': 100, 'medium': 1.5, 'diameter': 40.0}
{'density': 1, 'thickness': 100, 'medium': 2, 'diameter': 20.0}
{'density': 1, 'thickness': 100, 'medium': 2, 'diameter': 30.0}
{'density': 1, 'thickness': 100, 'medium': 2, 'diameter': 40.0}
...
```

Comment: this isn't a complete answer, so probably should not be posted as-is, if you want to give hints/tips it should be a comment imo

Comment: Depends how you define a complete answer. If you mean copy/paste-ready answers then it is not what SO should be used for. The answer should contain the 'way how to do it', which this answer does, but not necessarily a copy/paste code like a gist repo.